# Is this C# casting useless?

Tags: c#-3.0, casting

I have two methods like so:

```
Foo[] GetFoos(Type t) { //do some stuff and return an array of things of type T }

T[] GetFoos<T>()
    where T : Foo
{
    return GetFoos(typeof(T)) as T[];
}
```

However, this always seems to return null. Am I doing things wrong or is this just a shortfall of C#?

Nb:
I know I could solve this problem with:

```
GetFoos(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToArray();
```

However, I would prefer to do this wothout any allocations (working in an environment very sensitive to garbage collections).

Nb++:
Bonus points if you suggest an alternative non allocating solution

*Edit:
This raises an interesting question. The MSDN docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx say that the cast will succeed if there is an implicit or explicit cast. In this case there is an explicit cast, and so the cast should succeed. Are the MSDN docs wrong?*

Comment: what happens when you do this:  `(T[])GetFoos(typeof(T))`

Comment: Will: `InvalidCastException`. If `as` returns `null`, a direct cast won't be successful.

Comment: Is `GetFoos()` implementation locked and you can't change it?  Probably the most ideal situation (aside from using generics) would be if it returned a non-specific `Array` instead.  Then it could return an array of stuff of that type and you can safely cast it to the type you need.

Comment: @Femaref: Correct, just tested it :)

Comment: @Jeff: It *can* be changed, but it's a pita. an Array can be cast to any type I assume, with a runtime exception if it's the wrong type?

Comment: @Jeff (again): See my first comment to Fefmarefs answer below for the reason for not using generics. There is method in this madness ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, C# casting isn't useless - you simply can't cast a `Foo[]` to a `T[]` where `T` is a more derived type, as the `Foo[]` could contain other elements different to `T`. Why don't you adjust your `GetFoos` method to `GetFoos<T>()`? A method only taking a `Type` object can easily be converted into a generic method, where you could create the array directly via `new T[]`.

If this is not possible: Do you need the abilities an array offers (ie. indexing and things like `Count`)? If not, you can work with an `IEnumerable<T>` without having much of a problem. If not: you won't get around going the `Cast<T>.ToArray()` way.

Edit:

There is no possible cast from `Foo[]` to `T[]`, the description in your link is the other way round - you could cast a `T[]` to a `Foo[]` as all `T` are `Foo`, but not all `Foo` are `T`.

Comment: Unfortunately an enumerable allocates every time you enumerate it, which is why we're using arrays in the first place. The GetFoos taking a type looks up the array in a dictionary of Type->Foo[], so ultimately even the generic method would still use types internally. And we can't store more specifically typed arrays because all the value types in a dictionary have to be the same

Comment: Hm, it allocates an `IEnumerator<T>`, that's correct. But it won't allocate memory for each element everytime. The memory comsumption is only depended on your quantity of enumerators.

Comment: Sorry, by "enumerate it" I meant each time you start a new enumeration of the collection it will allocate (a new IEnumerator). I could try passing the IEnumerator around and calling reset lots, but that's horribly ugly!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your environment? Just curious.

Comment: Writing an game for the xbox 360 using XNA. unfortunately the Xbox uses a non fgenerational GC, which means collections can take quite a while. And in the middle of a game a stutter of half a second is *very* noticeable. So we have to work to a minimum of collections, in theory *none* during the gameplay phase with everything being allocated during loading screens.

Comment: Also, I just unaccepted your answer because i added a little to the question.

Comment: Ah okay, that's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If you can arrange for `GetFoos` to create the return array using `new T[]`, then you win. If you used `new Foo[]`, then the array's type is fixed at that, regardless of the types of the objects it actually holds.

Comment: That's an interesting fact. Unfortunately in this case I think coverting to using new T[] would be difficult, as the arrays are created somewhere else that knows nothing of the more derived types :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it should work:

```
T[] array = Array.ConvertAll<Foo, T>(input,
    delegate(Foo obj)
    {
        return (T)obj;
    });
```

You can find more at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

I think this converts in-place, so it won't be doing any re-allocations.

Comment: Unfortunately from the docs it looks like it doesn't covert in place :(

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your situation, using `System.Array` in place of a more specific array can help you.  Remember, `Array` is the base class for all strongly typed arrays so an `Array` reference can essentially store any array.  You should make your (generic?) dictionary map `Type -> Array` so you may store any strongly typed array also while not having to worry about needing to convert one array to another, now it's just type casting.

i.e.,

```
Dictionary<Type, Array> myDict = ...;
Array GetFoos(Type t)
{
    // do checks, blah blah blah
    return myDict[t];
}
// and a generic helper
T[] GetFoos<T>() where T: Foo
{
    return (T[])GetFoos(typeof(T));
}

// then accesses all need casts to the specific type
Foo[] f = (Foo[])GetFoos(typeof(Foo));
DerivedFoo[] df = (DerivedFoo[])GetFoos(typeof(DerivedFoo));
// or with the generic helper
AnotherDerivedFoo[] adf = GetFoos<AnotherDerivedFoo>();
// etc...
```

p.s., The MSDN link that you provide shows how arrays are covariant.  That is, you may store an array of a more derived type in a reference to an array of a base type.  What you're trying to achieve here is contravariance (i.e., using an array of a base type in place of an array of a more derived type) which is the other way around and what arrays can't do without doing a conversion.